# How to say "Fear makes my heart beat faster"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, verb, verb-usage

How do you say:

> Fear makes my heart beat faster, my hands cold and head ache a little.

Here are my attempts:

> Angst verursacht, dass das Herz mir schneller klopft, meine Hände kälter werden und Kopf ein wenig schmerzen.
>   Angst macht mich das Herzklopfen, kalte Hände und ein wenig
>   Kopfschmerzen.

Comment: You should indicate in what context you want to use this. Is it in written language, e.g. in an essay? Or is it in informal oral communication with your friends. That makes an enormous difference. A typical oral expression would be "Von Angst krieg ich Herzrasen". Everything using "versursachen" would be met only in written communication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence

> Angst verursacht, dass das Herz mir schneller klopft, meine Hände kälter werden und Kopf ein wenig schmerz**t**.

is grammatically correct, but the second attempt isn't really fine.
I say *grammatically* because these sound very odd.

Terms actually used could be:

> Angst lässt mein Herz rasen(/schneller schlagen), meine Hände frieren(/kalt werden) und meinen Kopf schmerzen.

OR

> Angst verursacht bei mir Herzrasen, kalte Hände und Kopfschmerzen.

Comment: Shouldn'T it be "mein Kopf" to be totally correct? Good suggestions though

Comment: Maybe you could add the more basic "Wenn ich Angst habe, schlägt mein Herz schneller..." I think this is what people would most likely say in spoken German.

Comment: @Emanuel you could put "mein Kopf", however the pronoun of Hände (meine) applies to Kopf aswell.
Pronouns extend to everything state behind them, even in a list, UNLESS otherwise stated.
As said you could as well say "mein Kopf" but the unneccessary redundancy would sound strange.


As for "Wenn ich Angst habe": Its a stylistic choice I guess. I say it the way I put it, but there's of course many more ways.

Comment: I have to disagree. The pronoun only extends if the gender matches or at least if the pronoun matches... "Meine Hände/mein Kopf". If you were to extend the "meine" you'd be implying "meine Kopf" which is wrong. Since it is not the same gender and one is singular while the other is plural, there is no redundancy there, anyway.